# Aggregate a DataFrame using multiple conditions in groupby

Tags: python, aggregation, groupby

I have a dataframe with many duplicates. I have determined rules for duplicate identification, for example :

- If `street_name` AND `company_name` are equal => duplicates (condition A)
- If `company_name` AND `municipality` are equal => duplicates (condition B)
- If `company_name` AND `publisher_name` are equal => duplicates (condition C)
- etc.

Two records are the same if any of these conditions are met, so :
condition_A or condition B or condition C.

### Input

In my dataframe I have represented each condition as a cluster. That means, if two rows meet the condition A, they will have the same cluster in column `condition_A_cluster`.

| id | condition_A_cluster | condition_B_cluster | condition_C_cluster | field_to_aggregate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1€ |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 3 | 2€ |
| 3 | 2 | 3 | 5 | 9€ |
| 4 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 10€ |

### Desired Output

I want to have the following output :

| id_list | aggretated_field (sum) |
| --- | --- |
| 1,2,3 | 12€ |
| 4 | 10€ |

I imagine doing it in two ways :

- Directly, with something like : `df.groupby(condition_A_cluster or condition_B_cluster or condition_C_cluster).agg(...)`
- Sequentially, by grouping first by `condition_A_cluster`, then `condition_B_cluster` and finally by `condition_C_cluster`. The problem is that the first aggregation will transform condition condition_B_cluster and condition_C_cluster into "list" or clusters which starts to complicate things.

Is there any elegant way to do this in python ?

Comment: Clearly if rows 1, 4, and 7 have the same `condition_A_cluster` then you want them grouped. But what if rows 4, 10, and 11 share the same `condition_B_cluster`? Implicitly, it sound like you're looking to have them grouped together with 1, 4, 7 to create a unified cluster with 1, 4, 7, 10, 11. Is that your intention? If so, this process can require several iterations until it converges. It doesn't happen naturally with `groupby`. If this is your intention, then look into `sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering` with Hamming as the distance metric to resolve your clusters.